# How to use sequelize count with group to count total # of groups

Tags: sequelize.js

I have some data that has a `created_at` field. I have written a sequelize `findAll` query that successfully groups `created_at` dates which happen on the same day (ignoring hour, minute, second). I then return the `result.length` of that list to get the total # of unique days (that is my end goal). However, I was wondering if I could somehow use the sequelize `count` method to return the total # of unique days, instead of using `findAll` and then returning `result.length`

I haven't tried much because I am just learning sequelize and am a bit stumped. I also got to a place where I got my desired results, but I am hoping to find a way to use `count` instead of `findAll`.

```
const start = moment().subtract(9, 'months').format();
const end = moment().format();
const results = await models.route.unscoped().count({
    attributes: [[db.literal(`DATE("created_at")`), "date"]],
    group: [db.literal(`DATE("created_at")`), "date"],
    where: {
      created_at: {
        $between: [start, end]
      }
    },
    raw: true
  })
```

expected result: the result of the sequelize query to return a # which corresponds to total # of unique days found.
actual result: currently the result of the query is returning an array of all the unique dates, making me have to use `results.length` to get a total count of unique dates.

Answer (score 0):

Should work if you move your db.literal to the col attribute... roughly:

```
   results = await models.route.unscoped().count({
      col : db.fn('DATE', db.col('created_at')),
      distinct : true,
      where : // ...whatever...
     });
```

... but when I test, it appears that col must be a column... not a function result.  But, you can make it work with findAll(), roughly:

```
results = await models.route.unscoped().findAll({
  attributes: [[Sequelize.literal('COUNT (DISTINCT (DATE(created_at)))'), 'myCount']],
  where : // ...whatever...
});
```